# Regex to match complete, arbitrary-length, typeful LDAP name

Tags: python, regex, ldap

I'm trying to use Python 3.4.0 to pull typeful LDAP FDNs out of a log file (checking each line for a match.) None of the regex patterns I've tried work, however. I need to be able to find the full FDN, regardless of the type of the first element of the FDN (e.g. DC,OU,CN).

```
log_line1 = 'This server name is "CN=Server001,OU=SomeOU,DC=MyDom,DC=org".'
log_line2 = 'Whereas this server is called "cn=Server002,ou=SubContainer,ou=Elsewhere,dc=SubDomain,dc=MyDom,dc=org" and "something else" is also in quotes most likely.'
```

I'm okay with finding each *element* of the FDN and concatenating them myself. The closest I've come is this, which pretty much finds every word in the string:

```
>>> ldappattern = re.compile("cn=[\w-]+,|ou=[\w-]+,|dc=[\w-]+,", re.IGNORECASE)
>>> re.findall(ldappattern, log_line1)
['This', 'server', 'name', 'is', 'CN=Server001,', 'OU=SomeOU,', 'DC=MyDom,', 'DC=org']
```

Note that these LDAP names can contain spaces, so whitespace searches are pretty useless, and I can't guarantee that the last element will be anything sensible (e.g. I've seen `'DC=testcompany,DC=internal'` as the root elements of a domain, and even single-label DNS names for domains.) They should be in quotes, but they won't necessarily be the only thing in quotes on a given line.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you, you want to capture the name and value of each element in strings like it:

```
CN=Server001,OU=SomeOU,DC=MyDom,DC=org
```

The following regex is one way to do it. Note that the ending comma must be optional (and it's best to add a word boundary before it), or you'll miss the last element:

```
(cn|ou|dc)=([\w-]+)\b,?
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/_pjBK45nIjUYV8EC)

The name of each item is in capture group 1, and value in group two. It requires the ignore-case flag, as you know.

> "Note that these LDAP names can contain spaces, so whitespace searches are pretty useless"

I don't understand. Your posted demo input contains no spaces.

Comment: Regarding whitespace: `CN=Server001,OU=Some OU,DC=MyDom,DC=org` is also valid. However, `re.findall("(cn|ou|dc)=([\w\s-]+)\b,?", log_line1)` returns a list of tuples: `[('CN', 'Server001'), ('OU', 'Some OU'), ... ]` which works well enough for my purposes. There's probably a more efficient answer, and I'd love to see someone come up with it, but I can move forward with this.

Comment: Just change the character class from `[\w-]` to `[-\w  ]`, and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise always rawing your regex strings to avoid any sorts of bad surprises. This said, I would then suggest this regex:

```
(?:cn|ou|dc)=[^,"]+
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/xT0oB0)

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/xmpdtQ)

I used single quotes for the regex string so that I wouldn't have to escape the double quote I have in the regex.

`(?:cn|ou|dc)` matches any of `cn`, `ou` or `dc`.

`[^,"]+` matches any character except `,` and `"`.

Comment: What does "rawing" mean?

Comment: @aliteralmind this means you won't have to double escape stuff. Say you want to match one backslash. You'd need `'\\\\'` to match a single backslash. Rawing the string enables you to use `'\\'` to match a single backslash. See [the docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) .